# Speed up pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, rolling-computation

I want to speedup my code that I used `pandas.rolling().apply()` for custom function. The code below is worked fine but it is super slow. Is there any way to speedup it when applying with million of rows.

```
for i in [12, 9, 6, 3]:
    df[f'want_col_{i}'] = df.groupby(['account'])['types'].rolling(window = i).apply(lambda x: sum(x == 1)).values
```

The idea is to count value in given rolling window. For example, from the code above I like to count value is equal to `1` group by `account` by given window `12, 9, 6, 3` respectively.

Is there anyway to increse the speed, thanks!

Comment: Could you add the input and the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
df['types_eq_1'] = df['types'].eq(1).astype(int)

for i in [12, 9, 6, 3]:
    df[f'want_col_{i}'] = df.groupby(['account'])['types_eq_1'].rolling(window = i).sum()

df = df.drop('types_eq_1', 1)
```